# Custom LWC datatable with custom datatype - lightning Combo box

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, data-types

I need help in getting the values in the parent component from the template which is called in child. In below code,
onchange event is giving me the Id for the picklist value but not the cell id. how can I achieve this?

Ask is: I want the key-field or the name along with the picklist value when it is selected?

Parent component

```
  <template if:true={zipcodeList}>
                    <div class="slds-m-right_none slds-m-top_none slds-align_absolute-center" style="overflow: visible;width: 1400px;">
                        
                        <c-custom-types style="width:614px;"
                                key-field="Id"
                                data={zipsList}
                                columns={columns}
                                onrowselection={getSelectedRowName}
                                onchange={handleChange}
                                show-row-number-column>
                        </c-custom-types >
                    </div>
                </template>
```

Parent.js

````
   connectedCallback() {   
        this.fetchMarkets().then(() => {
            this.arrOfZipcode = this.zipcodeswm.split(',');
            this.zipsList = this.getzipsList();
        });
       
    }
    
    getzipsList() {
        let arrOfZipcode = this.zipcodeswm.split(',');
        const transformedArray = arrOfZipcode.map(value => {
            return { Name: value, Id: value };
        });
        this.zipcodeList = transformedArray;
        const c = transformedArray.map(record => {
            return {
                ...record,
                'picklistOptions': this.LstOfMarkets
            };
        });
        return c;
    }
    fetchMarkets() {  
        return getMarkets().then((result) => {
            this.LstOfMarkets = Object.entries(result).map(([key, value]) => {
                return {
                    label: value,
                    value: key
                };
            });
        
            for (const key in result) {
                if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    const value = result[key]; 
                    this.marketMap.set(key, value); // key=id and value= name
                }
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.error = error;
            this.cases = undefined;
        });
    }



    // this is triggered when a row selected
    getSelectedRowName(event) {
       const conf = event.detail.config;
        const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        
    }
   
    handleChange(event) {
        console.log('event.detail- handleCellChange', event.detail.value);
// HERE THIS EVENT HAS ONLY VALUE BUT THERE IS NO CELL INFO
    }

    ```
 customTypes LWC Component
````

**customPicklist.html**

```
    <div class="slds-m-right_none slds-m-top_none slds-align_absolute-center" style="overflow: visible;">
     <lightning-combobox
            name="picklist"
            label={typeAttributes.label}
            value={typeAttributes.value} -- ** how to get the value from here to parent for which row this value belong to**
            placeholder={typeAttributes.placeholder}
            options={typeAttributes.options}
            >
        </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
</template>
```

customTypes.html

```
<template></template>
```

customTypes.js

```
   import customPicklist from './customPicklist.html';
   export default class CustomTypes extends LightningDatatable {
    //global var
    static customTypes= {
        marketPicklist: {
            template: customPicklist,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['label', 'placeholder', 'options', 'value', 'context', 'variant','name']
        }
    }

   }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). From what you've shared, you haven't actually asked a question as such. What is the problem you're having issues with and what help are you asking for? Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich thanks for the tour, if you check the code i added a comment where I need help. but looks like you are expecting question as text, i am editing it now

Answer (score 0):

In customPicklist.html, add a custom event when the combobox value changes

In customPicklist.js, dispatch the custom event.

In c-custom-types.html, handle the custom event
onpicklistchange={handlePicklistChange}

In c-custom-types.js, handle the custom event.

handlePicklistChange(event) {
const selectedValue = event.detail.value;
// row logic
}
}

Comment: customPicklist.html is a template not LWC component

Comment: how to add custom event to a template?